# implicit declaration of function and undefined reference to

Tags: c, linux, makefile

About compile suricata.
In Makefile,when CFLAGS wrap "-Werror-implicit-function-declaration"
I got the error:

```
    detect-engine-siggroup.c: In function ‘SigGroupHeadFree’:
detect-engine-siggroup.c:187:9: error: implicit declaration of function ‘_mm_free’ [-Werror=implicit-function-declaration]
         SCFreeAligned(sgh->mask_array);
         ^
detect-engine-siggroup.c: In function ‘SigGroupHeadBuildHeadArray’:
detect-engine-siggroup.c:1715:5: error: implicit declaration of function ‘_mm_malloc’ [-Werror=implicit-function-declaration]
     sgh->mask_array = (SignatureMask *)SCMallocAligned((cnt * sizeof(SignatureMask)), 16);
```

When I delete "-Werror-implicit-function-declaration" in Makefile,I will got the error:

```
detect-engine-siggroup.o: In function `SigGroupHeadFree':
/root/suricata/suricata-2.0.9/src/detect-engine-siggroup.c:187: undefined reference to `_mm_free'
detect-engine-siggroup.o: In function `SigGroupHeadBuildHeadArray':
/root/suricata/suricata-2.0.9/src/detect-engine-siggroup.c:1715: undefined reference to `_mm_malloc'
```

Note:_mm_free and _mm_malloc is define in util-mem.h
Yet,I add some code in the other source file,but not in  detect-engine-siggroup.c and util-mem.h.
What's wrong?

in detect-engine-siggroup.c(note I have deleted some redundant code here):

```
void SigGroupHeadFree(SigGroupHead *sgh)
{
    if (sgh == NULL)
        return;

    SCLogDebug("sgh %p", sgh);

    PatternMatchDestroyGroup(sgh);

#if defined(__SSE3__) || defined(__tile__)
    if (sgh->mask_array != NULL) {
        /* mask is aligned */
        SCFreeAligned(sgh->mask_array);
        sgh->mask_array = NULL;
    }
#endif

    if (sgh->head_array != NULL) {
        SCFree(sgh->head_array);
        sgh->head_array = NULL;
    }

    if (sgh->match_array != NULL) {
        detect_siggroup_matcharray_free_cnt++;
        detect_siggroup_matcharray_memory -= (sgh->sig_cnt * sizeof(Signature *));
        SCFree(sgh->match_array);
        sgh->match_array = NULL;
    }

    sgh->sig_cnt = 0;

    if (sgh->init != NULL) {
        SigGroupHeadInitDataFree(sgh->init);
        sgh->init = NULL;
    }

    SCFree(sgh);

    detect_siggroup_head_free_cnt++;
    detect_siggroup_head_memory -= sizeof(SigGroupHead);

    return;
}
```

in util-mem.h(note I have deleted some redundant code here):

```
#ifndef __UTIL_MEM_H__
#define __UTIL_MEM_H__

#include "util-atomic.h"

#if CPPCHECK==1
#define SCMalloc malloc
#define SCCalloc calloc
#define SCRealloc realloc
#define SCFree free
#define SCStrdup strdup
#define SCMallocAligned _mm_malloc
#define SCFreeAligned _mm_free
#else /* CPPCHECK */


#if defined(_WIN32) || defined(__WIN32)
#include "mm_malloc.h"
#endif

#if defined(__tile__)
/* Need to define __mm_ function alternatives, since these are SSE only.
 */
#include <malloc.h>
#define _mm_malloc(a,b) memalign((b),(a))
#define _mm_free(a) free((a))
#endif /* defined(__tile__) */

SC_ATOMIC_EXTERN(unsigned int, engine_stage);

/* Use this only if you want to debug memory allocation and free()
 * It will log a lot of lines more, so think that is a performance killer */

/* Uncomment this if you want to print memory allocations and free's() */
//#define DBG_MEM_ALLOC

#ifdef DBG_MEM_ALLOC

#define SCFree(a) ({ \
    extern uint8_t print_mem_flag; \
    if (print_mem_flag == 1) {          \
        SCLogInfo("SCFree at %p", (a)); \
    }                                   \
    free((a)); \
})

#else /* !DBG_MEM_ALLOC */


#define SCFree(a) ({ \
    free(a); \
})

#if defined(__WIN32) || defined(_WIN32)

#define SCFreeAligned(a) ({ \
    _mm_free(a); \
})

#else /* !win */

#define SCFreeAligned(a) ({ \
    _mm_free((a)); \
})

#endif /* __WIN32 */

#endif /* DBG_MEM_ALLOC */

#endif /* CPPCHECK */

#endif /* __UTIL_MEM_H__ */

#endif /* DBG_MEM_ALLOC */

#endif /* CPPCHECK */

#endif /* __UTIL_MEM_H__ */
```

/*********************************************************************/

**Now solved the problem,reason is forgetting to** `#include <pmmintrin.h> /* for SSE3 */`

/*********************************************************************/

Comment: More information is needed, implicit declaration is due to the lack of a declaration for the function, removing that warning (or any warning) is bad, if you do it you are just hiding problems. Undefined reference means, that there is a lack of a definition too. Can you please post the code?

Comment: It would appear that you failed to include the correct header files and failed to link to the correct library.

Comment: this two source file can compile success when I did not added any my code in the other .c file,

Comment: What was the redundant code you deleted?  That's got to be the first suspect for "it wasn't quite as redundant as you thought".  It appears that the `util_mem.h` header isn't being included, or isn't being included in such a way that the declarations you need are made visible.  You'll need to track down why.  It may even come down to inspecting the preprocessed output from the C preprocessor (`gcc -E …`).  That's a dubious looking list of `#endif` directives at the end of `util-mem.h` — 3 of them are repeated.

Comment: Thanks  Etan Reisner and Jonathan Leffler,now I fix the bug.I have used gcc -E to check the output,and found that I have delete some code in  the other place,cause _mm_malloc and _mm_free undefined.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you have not included `util-mem.h` properly. `SCFreeAligned` seem to expand to `_mm_free`, but `_mm_free` doesn't seem to expand. Looking at the header file the definition of `_mm_free` seem to be dependent on `__title__` being defined.

Then the compiler just sees a call to `_mm_free` which is given an implicit prototype as `_mm_free` doesn't exist. Then of course `_mm_free` will not be found during linking.